# What is the worst case time complexity of unranking n choose k combinations (combinatorial number system, combinadics)

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, combinatorics, rank

The [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) shows that there is a bijection between the natural numbers less than $n \choose k$ and $n\choose k$ combinations. There is a [greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Finding_the_k-combination_for_a_given_number) for [unranking](https://oeis.org/wiki/Ranking_and_unranking_functions#:%7E:text=A%20ranking%20algorithm%20determines%20the,be%20considered%20as%20inverse%20operations.) combinations, which one may calculate the worst-case run time for. I'm curious: is this the fastest algorithm in terms of asymptotic worst-case run time? If not, what is the fastest algorithm, and what is the worst-case run time?

Comment: do you know the current complexity of this greedy algorithm? If so, please provide a reference for it.